# Create a loading bar when user clicks a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, loading

I need to create a loading bar when the user clicks a link and if necessary – to upload data (via Ajax) into `div#work`, then show the loading bar. When the data is uploaded then I want this script stopped, because I have files which are always loaded as background files. How to create this with jQuery?

ps: sorry but my english very bad :(

Comment: If you're uploading files, etc, then the only way to get a progress indicator is to use a Flash upload applet. If you just want to show a looping loading animation, go with @genesis' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ajax").click(function(){
   $("#work").show();

   $.post('data.php', {'data':'here'}, function(){
        $("#work").hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: it's solution but i want write more universal script. i know about ajaxStart() but it not suitable because i have background load page.

Comment: @Koiw: what does "background load page" mean ?

Comment: it page which uploading all of the time. I use it for checking different things.

Comment: for example
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function()
   {

   $('#friend_notice').load('notice_actions.php?action=check&notice=1');
   }, 5000);

Comment: @Koiw: so just place my code where you need, and keep background proccess without this loader